# Jquery array iteration with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push, each

```
var imgLink = ['ONYX', 'Bristol_Blue_B_002_10', 'Oakhampton_B_001_10-1', 'Quartet_KitchenCountertop_500x342', 'Eternal-Serena_RS11277_Silestone-Kitchen', 'zodiaq_provence_kitchen_2200x1467-b94f5-1', 'Eternal-Serena_RS11277_Silestone-Kitchen-1', 'Ecobycosentino-', 'Hanstone', 'IceStone-Forest-Fern-Shadowlight-Vignette-Kitchen-Countertop', 'RS833_Silversilk_OA-hpr-copy_CMYK', 'scalea'];

    var imgArray = [];

jQuery.each(imgLink, function(i){
    var img = jQuery('<img/>')

    .attr("src", "http://www.link.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/" +imgLink[i]+ ".jpg")
    imgArray.push(img[i]);  
});
console.log(imgArray);
```

Hello ,everybody , I have a code above and my  goal it's to make an array images with attributes but the results right now is

[image: Results of array]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ar2zee/jgfarys0/)

can anybody give me advise what I'm doing wrong , Thank you!

Comment: Only the first one works, because when i is 0, you are pushing the DOM node into the array, `img[1]` and onwards makes no sense. You should be using `imgArray.push(img)` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
imgArray.push(img[i]);
```

should be:

```
imgArray.push(img); // <-- img is not an array
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var imgLink = ['ONYX', 'Bristol_Blue_B_002_10', 'Oakhampton_B_001_10-1', 'Quartet_KitchenCountertop_500x342', 'Eternal-Serena_RS11277_Silestone-Kitchen', 'zodiaq_provence_kitchen_2200x1467-b94f5-1', 'Eternal-Serena_RS11277_Silestone-Kitchen-1', 'Ecobycosentino-', 'Hanstone', 'IceStone-Forest-Fern-Shadowlight-Vignette-Kitchen-Countertop', 'RS833_Silversilk_OA-hpr-copy_CMYK', 'scalea'];

var imgArray = [];

jQuery.each(imgLink, function(key, value) {
  var img = jQuery('<img/>').attr("src", "http://www.link.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/" + value + ".jpg")

  // uncomment below for img 
  //imgArray.push(img);

  // just html for testing
  imgArray.push(img[0]);
});
console.log(imgArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```